# Buddypress behind AWS ELB

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, amazon-elb

I've inherited a buddypress application that needs to be made more scalable. We moved everything to aws and put the site behind a load balancer as part of having a build pipeline. The problem is that buddypress relies on the local filesystem for user uploaded photos. What is the easiest and/or most maintainable way to break the reliance on the EC2 instance's file system?

I'm considering S3FS or plugging into/rewriting the buddypress avatar code, but I'm open to other possibilities.

Comment: I'm assuming you've done some googling? http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/hosting-on-amazon-web-services

Comment: I hadn't actually come across that page before. I came in to this situation with the app running on a wp hosting provider, and the company had a fair bit of AWS credits available to them. There is a lot of work left to do on the app, and we don't expect to be with wp/bp forever, and assumed we would eventually end up on AWS anyways. So the move to AWS was made. The current app is just running on an EC2 instance, which isn't very nice to integrate with a build pipeline, hence the move to the ELB.

Comment: My understanding is that AWS is going to be a pain. If you are planning on moving off of WP/BP eventually *and* eventually moving to AWS, why not host on something more appropriate now and move to AWS when you're ready, and it's less of a pain?

Comment: I did write this at some point in the past, it might be useful to you: http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/moving-wordpress-wp-contentuploads-out-of-your-documentroot/

Comment: That WP2Cloud option looks pretty good. I was worried they'd be doing a lot of network stuff when bp is having all of its filesystem fun, but it looks like they just fake it with their own avatar directory. I'm going to try that out.

Comment: We're also trying to cut our costs as low as possible, so if we can manage to use free money for AWS, we'd prefer to. Though you're right. The amount of work it's taken to get us up and running there (sort of) has been more than I expected.

Comment: Depending on your AWS deployment region you might try the AWS Elastic File System (EFS) Preview (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) to store the static content.